# Help me identify this part in Hitachi CP-X445 projector

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, diodes

I have this old Hitachi CP-X445 projector. And it stopped working. after opening it up I started it and this small thing started smoking and became ashes. What is it? Where can I find it? What is the full name with values? It was just like the rest three of them. I have a multi meter but don't know how to check the values.

[image]

Comment: L reference is usually either an inductor or a ferrite bead. Since those traces are thick and probably carry power, I suspect you have a short somewhere downstream of the connector.

Comment: Given the green corrosion on the chip at bottom and fuzzy vias, chance of repair is very low.  Board is in bad shape.  Burning the L was a symptom of another problem.

Comment: " I suspect you have a short somewhere downstream of the connector. "  ...meaning that just replacing the part will likely result in the need to replace the part again.  The problem likely lies elsewhere...

Comment: Agree with rdtsc, just in the small part of the board shown you can see a lot of moisture damage. Dull dark grey solder joints, green on the IC pins (that means that the corrosion is through the tin plating and into the copper underneath), and dark spots around the vias are all bad signs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone finds a service manual, or rather, a schematic with detailed bill of material, the actual part (i.e. manufacturer and exact type, value, and properties for the part) will remain unknown.

Despite the designator L for the L804 part, it is not a simple chip inductor or even a simple chip ferrite bead.

It does not have only two terminals for input and output, but there is a third terminal for ground in the middle on the sides of the part.

Therefore it is a three terminal filter, comparable to Murata EMIFIL parts in the NFM, NFL/NFW/NFA, or NFE series. But it might not be any of the above or even any Murata part.

So fortuntely, after fixing the downstream fault or short circuit that caused this part to damage could for test purposes be replaced with a standard ferrite bead of random value, 0R resistor, or jumper wire. It's just a noise filter and likely for power supply wire.

But it is sure that there is a short circuit somewhere downstream and just replacing this part will just make it burn again like a fuse.